# How to extract Currency Values from Multiple Strings stored in different ways?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I have multiple types of strings in a dataframe's colume like :

"Dear ... INR 2,36,22,217.29 on Date 2018-12-22 11:33:42 AM ..... No 8356111112294....."

with the currency being written broadly in INR XX, Rs. XX,Rs.XX,INRXX,RS XX , etc and other ways with/without commas like 2,30,000 and 230000 .

So I basically want to extract the Currency value i.e. 230000 in a new column in the data frame in R.

How can I do it for multiple strings with different sentence structures as well as different ways in which currency is written as explained above.

ALso I am a beginner so please explain the best way. 
Also if It's possible to solve this via ML (which I dont know how to use) then please lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work as long as the value is always preceded with RS or INR (with or without a "." and ignoring case) ...

```
sub(".*[INR\\.*|RS\\.*] ([\\d.]+)\\s+(\\S+).*", "\\1", gsub(",", "", vec), perl = T, ignore.case = T)  
# [1]  "23622217.29" "23622217.29" "23622217.29"
```

---

**Data:**

```
vec <- c("Dear ... INR 2,36,22,217.29 on Date 2018-12-22 11:33:42 AM ..... No 8356111112294.....",
         "Dear ... RS. 2,36,22,217.29 on Date 2018-12-22 11:33:42 AM ..... No 8356111112294.....",
         "Dear ... Rs 2,36,22,217.29 on Date 2018-12-22 11:33:42 AM ..... No 8356111112294.....")
```

Comment: It is not resolving for those which do not have a gap like Rs.1000 or RS10000 etc otherwise it works excellent!!!! Thanks a lot, if you could also let me know how to resolve the gap issue , it would be great.

Comment: Also there's a problem where it delete's the Rs Amount which is mentioned first and only keeps the one on the left for example : " Your UBI AC XX492298 is credited by Rs 300.0 on 24-11-2018 14:31:54.Clear AC Bal Rs 10400.0. Info:UPI/83281441........." 

The output should be the leftmost i.e. 300, not 10400